# Is there an easy way to identify objects?

Tags: kotlin

I have a custom `lazy` implementation which allows for specifying a key function which is then called on every property access and if its return value doesn't equal the last one the initializer is called again.

So is there something straightforward to specify as key function to let the implementation check whether a specific variable x holds a reference to another object than before? Some value that is unique to an object?

```kotlin
var x = MyClass()

val myValue by lazy(key = x::IDENTIFIER) { ... }
```

Otherwise I would have to let my custom implementation accept a `(KeyType, KeyType) -> Boolean` function, so that I could let it use the referential equality operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you can write a wrapper that wraps any class. That wrapper's `equals` will use `===` to compare the wrapped values.

```
class Identity<T>(val value: T) {
    
    override fun hashCode(): Int = value?.hashCode() ?: 0 // or use System.identityHashCode()
    
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as Identity<*>

        return value === other.value
    }
}
```

Then the key function can just be `{ x: SomeType -> Identity(x) }`. It will create two `Identity` objects that are equal by `==`, for two `x`s that are equal by `===`.